# Why is working with a local copy of ThreadLocal's Value member faster although it is a reference type?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm following the example on page 107 of Patterns for Parallel Programming: Understanding and Applying Parallel Patterns with the .NET Framework 4 (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=19222). It is stated that using a local copy of the ThreadLocal's Value member is faster compared to using Threadlocal.Value itself. I tested this and it is indeed the case. But why?

As can be seen in the code, a local copy of _vector2.Value is saved in vector2 and this local copy is used to sum all items. If you use
    `_vector2.Value[i] += _vector1.Value[i]`
instead of
    `vector2[i] += vector1[i]`
the code runs just as well albeit slower. This is what is stated in the article. Now int[] is a reference type. This means that when you make a copy in vector2 you are actually copying a reference the original int[] in ThreadLocal's Value member. This is corroborated by commenting out `_vector2.Value = vector2`. The printed result remains the same. So, I don't think this assignment is needed.

Now, since _vector2.Value and vector2 are referencing the same data, how is it possible that working with the local copy (vector2) is still faster? Approximately 4 times faster in my test. Has anyone any idea what I'm missing?

```cs
    class ReferenceList
    {
        const int VECTOR_LENGTH = 100000000;
        private ThreadLocal<int[]> _vector1 = new ThreadLocal<int[]>(() => Enumerable.Range(1, VECTOR_LENGTH).ToArray());
        private ThreadLocal<int[]> _vector2 = new ThreadLocal<int[]>(() => Enumerable.Range(1, VECTOR_LENGTH).ToArray());

        internal void DoWork()
        {
            int[] vector1 = _vector1.Value;
            int[] vector2 = _vector2.Value;

            for (int i = 0; i < VECTOR_LENGTH; i++)
            {
                // This is the fast way (as in the document)
                vector2[i] += vector1[i];

                // This is the slow way
                //_vector2.Value[i] += _vector1.Value[i];
            }

            // Since int[] is a reference type. This step is not needed, I think. The result is not influenced when commenting out this line
            _vector2.Value = vector2;

            Console.WriteLine($"Thread-{Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId} Result: {String.Join(", ", _vector2.Value.Take(10))}");
        }
```

Comment: A somewhat useful mental model is to think of a thread-local variable as a `Dictionary<int, T>` whose key is the thread's ManagedId.  Accessing that dictionary is always more expensive than accessing a variable that doesn't have that behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`vector1` is a reference **directly** to the array. *Nothing is ever going to be faster than that.*

`_vector1` is **not** a reference directly to the array. `_vector1.Value` will *result* in the same value - but it takes it some effort to get that value, as per [the source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/ThreadLocal.cs,268). Thus, every time you ask for `.Value` you take that performance hit (of executing methods etc) again (even though **you** know it will return the same value, it takes it some effort to work that out). *And that is ignoring other related costs like possible reduction in data locality, increased cache misses etc.*

Comment: Thank you, I didn't known the source code is available. I couldn't understand that passing through an instance member could introduce such a delay, but now I've seen the code I understand.